# What do I need to do to my python code to get it to be a module?

Tags: python, module, setuptools, distutils

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong to package this as a module: 
https://github.com/xamox/python-zxing.

My setup.py is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='zxing',
    version='0.1',
    description="wrapper for zebra crossing (zxing) barcode library",
    url='http://simplecv.org',
    author='Ingenuitas',
    author_email='public.relations@ingenuitas.com',
    packages=['zxing'],
)
```

I am trying to do "import zxing". I do setup.py install, puts it in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/, but import zxing doesn't work.

I get the following error:

```
In [1]: import zxing.zxing
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResolutionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/xamox/<ipython-input-1-9ff7d0755c55> in <module>()
----> 1 import zxing.zxing

/usr/local/bin/zxing.py in <module>()
      3 __requires__ = 'zxing==0.1'
      4 import pkg_resources
----> 5 pkg_resources.run_script('zxing==0.1', 'zxing.py')

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.pyc in run_script(self, requires, script_name)
    465         ns.clear()
    466         ns['__name__'] = name
--> 467         self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
    468 
    469 

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.pyc in run_script(self, script_name, namespace)
   1192         script = 'scripts/'+script_name
   1193         if not self.has_metadata(script):
-> 1194             raise ResolutionError("No script named %r" % script_name)
   1195         script_text = self.get_metadata(script).replace('\r\n','\n')
   1196         script_text = script_text.replace('\r','\n')

ResolutionError: No script named 'zxing.py'
```

Comment: What is the file name of this module?  Does it work in your local directory?

Comment: It works in my local directory, but after running setup.py install and try to import I get the following error:
https://gist.github.com/b51c37cb5ac13557539d

Comment: Please copy and past the actual text of the error message into this question.  Chasing down links is unacceptable.  Please find the words in the error message, please copy them.  Please **update** the question with the words. Also.  Please include your `setup.py` script that supposedly installed your module.

Comment: Done, and updated above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look in the stack trace whose URL you showed in a comment:

```
/usr/local/bin/zxing.py in <module>()
      3 __requires__ = 'zxing==0.1'
      4 import pkg_resources
----> 5 pkg_resources.run_script('zxing==0.1', 'zxing.py')
```

That indicates that it is trying to load some guff from `/usr/local/bin/zxing.py` which contains code that's not in your current version e.g. "import pkg_resources". Looks like debris from a previous experiment. Get rid of it.

Now that you have a clean deck:

It seems rather pointless having an empty `__init__.py` and a one-source-file package. I suggest that you delete the `__init__.py` and remove all traces of other experiments (especially "build" directories). If there is a folder `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zxing`, remove it.

Comment: That was my problem.  For some reason that script was laying around from the last time.  I also had to change the file to __init__.py, thanks for that tid-bit as I was having to do import zxing.zxing.

Comment: I don't understand "I also had to change the file to" `__init__.py` or `init.py` or whatever else you intended to type. Did you read the last paragraph of my answer?

Answer (score 6):

When you do

```
import zxing.zxing
```

everything works (`dir(zxing.zxing) = ['BarCode', 'BarCodeReader', ...]`). Probably you want people just have to use

```
import zxing
```

If that is what you want, you have to put the following code to `zxing/__init__.py`

```
from zxing import *
```

Or much better

```
from zxing import BarCode, BarcodeReader, ...
```

Comment: Actually that didn't work.  It works if I run it from that directory, like locally if I run python from that directory.  What happens after I run python setup.py install, that seems to work, then I open ipython , and get the following: 
https://gist.github.com/b51c37cb5ac13557539d